# Got access denied when tried to enable Hyper-V through Powershell command with Serial Console on a Windows Server 2019 VM (Azure)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, windows-server-2019, azure-vm

I created a VM with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter image in Azure. Due to company policy, we are not allow to have a public IP and port. The only way to access the VM is using the Serial Console.

I was able to run PowerShell in serial console. However, I got the access problem.

Error:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Win32 internal error "Access is denied" 0x5
occurred while reading the console output buffer. Contact Microsoft Customer
Support Services.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature],
   HostException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadConsoleOutput,Microsoft.Dism.Commands.Enable
   WindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

I tried to [elevate the Powershell prompt](https://serverfault.com/questions/464018/run-elevated-powershell-prompt-from-command-line), but no luck. The account I created should have admin access. I wonder there is any way I can get this working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is some limitation on the Server 2019 Datacenter image because I also get the same error but it worked on the Server 2016 datacenter refer to [this](http://techtalk.cloud/how-to-connect-to-an-azure-vm-using-the-serial-console/).

[image]

As a workaround, If the Azure VM does not have a public IP address assigned, I suggesting run PowerShell scripts within the Azure VM via [run command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command). The feature uses the virtual machine (VM) agent to run PowerShell scripts within an Azure Windows VM. For more information about running scripts in your Windows VM, you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-scripts-in-vm).

For example, you can enable hyper-v via PowerShell Scripts

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```

Then Invoke the scripts via `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`cmdlet to run a PowerShell script on an Azure VM. The cmdlet expects the script referenced in the `-ScriptPath` parameter to be local to where the cmdlet is being run.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nancy for your great answer. Using the VM agent to run PS scripts (within VM) works for me. I am a bit confused about the last part you mention. I tried to run `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` on my local machine. It seems the command is not recognized as a cmdlet. Can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `run command` via the Azure portal, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#azure-portal). With PowerShell, You need to install [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.6.1) first. Also, you need a nesting capable Azure VM to enable nested virtualization in an Azure VM. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error message today, and I noticed I have an active RDP session to the target machine and with Windows PowerShell opened (for test purposes).

So I just tried to exit the PowerShell and close the RDP session, then it works!